# What's the halacha with regards to Maaser for a Baal Teshuvah?

Tags: money, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, baal-teshuva

Say a person never gave charity, due to ignorance or whatever other reason. He has now become a Baal Teshuvah and started observing the Torah.

What is the halacha with charity? Does he have to give 10% of all his assets, 10% of everything he has ever made or just start from scratch and begin giving maaser with each new pay check?

Comment: Well I would assume it depends if we hold its a doraisa,drabbanan or minhag these days,this is a three way machlokes.

Comment: Depends on: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8846

Comment: R' Moshe Shternbuch has a [responsum](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&pgnum=405) about this very question. I don't have time to summarize it, maybe someone else can volunteer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh De'ah 249 סימן רמט - כמה חייב ליתן וכיצד יתננה says that **the first year one decides to start keeping Ma'aser Kesafim, on separates 1/5 or 1/10 of one's capital.**

After that, every year one separates 1/5 or 1/10 of the profit on one's income.

Since he starts with יִתֵּן עַד חֹמֶשׁ נְכָסָיו it would seem that he considers all one's assets as capital.

The entire Siman is:

> א שִׁעוּר נְתִינָתָהּ, אִם יָדוֹ מַשֶּׂגֶת, יִתֵּן כְּפִי צֹרֶךְ הָעֲנִיִּים. וְאִם אֵין יָדוֹ מַשֶּׂגֶת כָּל כָּךְ, יִתֵּן עַד חֹמֶשׁ נְכָסָיו, מִצְוָה מִן הַמֻּבְחָר; וְאֶחָד מֵעֲשָׂרָה, מִדָּה בֵּינוֹנִית; פָּחוֹת מִכָּאן, עַיִן רָעָה. וְחֹמֶשׁ זֶה  שֶׁאָמְרוּ, **שָׁנָה רִאשׁוֹנָה מֵהַקֶּרֶן, מִכָּאן וָאֵילָךְ חֹמֶשׁ שֶׁהִרְוִיחַ בְּכָל שָׁנָה**.

Comment: Wow, I wish I hadn't read this.